# Rails 4 - method to count a user's projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, count, counter

I'm trying to learn how to write a method that counts a user's projects in my Rails 4 app.

I have models called Project and Profile. The associations are:

Project

```
belongs_to :profile
```

Profile

```
has_many :projects
```

In my project model, I have a scope that finds projects by the profile_id.

```
scope :by_profile, ->(profile_id) { where(profile_id: profile_id) }
```

Now, I'm trying to write method to count how many projects the profile has made.

```
def project_counter
    # projects created by this project creator
    self.by_profile.count 

    # plus all the projects where the user is part of a project team


  end
```

When I save this and try to use it in the view:

```
<%= @project.project_counter %>
```

I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `by_profile' for #<Project:0x007f98f1dff278>
Did you mean?  profile
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: you called  `self.by_profile.count` without passing an `profile_id` try `self.by_profile(<user id here>.count`

Comment: I want to count the number of projects that belong to a user's profile. Should I really add user_id for that? User isn't directly associated to project. I'm trying to count the profile_ids in the projects table.

Comment: "In my project model, I have a scope that finds projects by the profile_id." you shouldn't need that... that's what the associations give you. if you want to know the number of projects for a given profile do this: `Profile.find(profile_id).projects.count`

Comment: @TarynEast - I don't know how I would initiate that from the projects view. Thanks anyway for the suggestion. I have found a way that works and that will be good enough for now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "initiating it from the view"? you just copy that code above and it should Just Work... ? It doesn't matter whether it's int he projects view or not

Comment: I don't understand that. I'm afraid your skill level is probable stratosphere's beyond mine. I think in the view I need to start with "@" to get the relevant object. Thanks for trying to help. I appreciate it - but I just don't understand that. I'll keep trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `<%= @project.project_counter %>`, @project is the context which refers to `self` inside the method. Note that `self` is the instance and not the class `Project`.

So, inside the method, when you call `self.by_profile`, what you're doing is calling `by_profile` on the instance. But `by_profile` is only available on the class Project and not an instance. That is why you're getting an `undefined method`by_profile' for #`. Here`#` refers to the instance(pointed by the memory location).

Also note that you're not passing a `profile_id` to `by_profile` but ruby won't complain about that cause its looking for an instance method `by_profile` and not a class method `by_profile`.(scope actually adds a class method)

If you want to count a user(profile's) projects, why not use `@project.user.projects.count`?

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Arun. That makes sense. I thought self meant the table rather than the instance. I didn't realise calling @project would override the value of self (as the class) to confine it to the table.  The reason for not counting user.projects.count is that I'm trying to display, on the projects page, how many other projects the profile has created. I'm not sure that I'll get the project creators count if I do it the way you have shown - I might get the current user's profile's projects instead.

Comment: @Mel  I don't understand. Do you want to display the profile's projects count(excluding the current project) on the projects#show page?
Something like `See 20 other projects by Anon`?
Is that you want?

Comment: I want to display the profile's project count (including this project) on the project page.

Comment: @Mel Updated the answer. Let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: - but project isn't associated directly with user. It's associated with profile.

Comment: I can try your idea thought with project.profile.projects.count

Comment: this is a variation of the idea I gave you, where instead of using `Profile.find` you use `project.profile`. It's the `.projects.count` part that is the relevant part - instead of rolling your own counting-code. :)